# In toroidal space, how to calculate which direction is the shortest between two points

Tags: geometry, coordinates

Basically I am creating an algorithm that plays the game of Snake independently. 
I have managed to make it work out which direction to head to within the square of the game, but the version of Snake that I made has toroidal space, namely that when the snake's head goes off one side of the square, it reappears on the opposite side.

On that basis, it is not important for me to calculate what the *distance* between two points (namely the snake's head and the food block), but rather what *direction* the food is in relation to the head.

I.e. on a grid of 50 pixels square, when the head is at [row 49, column 49] and the food is at [1,1], I don't want the snake to have to travel 48 squares up and to the left. I'd rather it just travel 2 squares down and 2 right.

What formula would I then use to calculate which direction will result in the shortest travel time between the head and the food?

PS please let me know if I should post this in another Stack Exchange site and I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to consider one dimensional case. Basically a circular buffer, see pic:

[image: 1-d representation of game]

You have the player "P" at position 3 and your "Goal" at position 9, and total play space Width = 10. The direction of shortest motion towards goal could then be given by:

```
if(P.coord < Goal.coord)
{
  int dist1 = Goal.coord - P.coord;
  int dist2 = (Width - Goal.coord) + P.coord;
  if(dist1 < dist2) 
  {
    //move forwards
  }
  else
  {
    //move backwards
  }
}
else
{
  int dist1 = P.coord - Goal.coord;
  int dist2 = (Width - P.coord) + Goal.coord;
  if(dist1 < dist2)
  {
    //move backwards
  }
  else
  {
    //move forwards
  }
}
```

Similarly handle the 'else' part if p>coord > Goal.coord. Now extend it to 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks Nicko! But what do I put in the `p.coord > Goal.coord` part? It looks like you've already accounted for all possibilities?